# dual boot total mess, what ways to continue?

Tags: linux, macos, multi-boot, linux-mint, macbook-pro-retina

I have a macbook pro and I wanted to switch to linux (mint, mate).
I have rEFInd installed and working, but everything is a total mess now.
So here are some questions.

In the rEFInd boot menu I have 3 big icons with:

> 1. "Boot EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi from EFI"
> 2. "Boot Mac OS X from Recovery HD"
> 3. "Boot Legacy OS from whole disk volume"

No.1 has only default boot options.
No.2 has something like default, verbose, single, safe, 32-bit, 64-bit
No.3 has Boot Legacy OS

- Legacy doesn't translate well to my language so I'm a bit lost. But shouldn't legacy not be the way you normally would boot if there was
  no boot loader?
- If I boot legacy I get "Missing Operating System".
- If I boot Recovery, I get into my OS with customised background, my downloads etc. (Is recovery just the name now?, or is this really messed up?)
- If I boot linux, I get a black screen after a logo. This happened after updating the video drivers to the recommended ones (and airport, but I don't think that is the problem).

Then I have the smaller icons with (not sure if this helps):

> - "Start Apple Recovery on Recovery HD"
> - "Start MDK utility at EFI\ubuntu\MokManager.efi on EFI"
> - "About rEFInd"
> - "Shut Down Computer"
> - "Reboot Computer"

What is the best thing to do now?

Comment: Please change your title, "smart" indicates you want opinions, which are not good answers.

Comment: Is running a VM insufficient? From personal experience, multi booting a Mac with Linux is always quirky at best.

Comment: I'm sick of Apple so I prefer not :)